# In Badminton, can the racket pass above the net in follow through?

Tags: rules, badminton

While playing badminton, is it a fault if the racket asses above net (doesn't touches it) in the follow through action?provided that it touches shuttle in my side itself.

I read in some blogs that it is not a fault, but I didn't find anything concrete. Can anyone point to official rules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Crossing the net with the racket after hitting it on your side is allowed, as laid out in §13.4.2 of the [laws of badminton](https://extranet.bwfbadminton.com/docs/document-system/81/1466/1470/Section%204.1%20-%20%20Laws%20of%20Badminton.pdf):

> It shall be a fault, if in play, a player invades an opponent's court over the net with racket or person except that the striker may follow the shuttle over the net with the racket in the course of a stroke after the initial point of
>   contact with the shuttle is on the striker’s side of the net;